# Writing-mode vertical text overflowing DIV

Tags: html, css

I have `p` tags within a `div` that is wider than it is high. One of the `p` has the writing mode set to `vertical-rl`. Although the text does wrap much of the text is clipped. It looks like the height of the `vertical-rl` `p` matches the width of the `div` so when it's rotated some of it is beyond the `div`.

**My Code:**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from left to right.</p>
  <p class="vertical-rl">This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from right to left.</p>
</div>
```

I have tried setting block-size and inline-size but I can't get the text to not be clipped. How can I have vertical-rl text wrap early enough that it doesn't overflow its container?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the p a max-height

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #0074d9;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from left to right.</p>
  <p class="vertical-rl">This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from right to left.</p>
</div>
```

You could calculate it too needed

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Select the container div
  const containerDiv = document.querySelector('div.container');

  // Get the computed style of the container div
  const containerStyle = window.getComputedStyle(containerDiv);

  // Calculate the total height of the container including padding
  // Note: Padding is included in offsetHeight, so we don't need to add it manually
  const containerHeight = containerDiv.offsetHeight;

  // Get the height of the first paragraph
  let firstParagraphHeight = document.querySelector('p:not(.vertical-rl)').offsetHeight;
  firstParagraphHeight += (2 * 20); // margins are NOT included
  // Calculate the new max-height for the vertical-rl paragraph by subtracting
  // the height of the first paragraph from the container's height
  const newMaxHeight = containerHeight - firstParagraphHeight;
  // console.log(containerHeight, firstParagraphHeight, newMaxHeight)

  // Apply this new max-height to the vertical-rl paragraph
  const verticalText = document.querySelector('.vertical-rl');
  verticalText.style.maxHeight = `${newMaxHeight}px`;
});
```

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from left to right.</p>
  <p class="vertical-rl">This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from right to left.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make the container a grid, so giving the second paragraph defined space:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.vertical-rl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  color: #0074d9;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from left to right.</p>
  <p class="vertical-rl">This is text that needs to be read from top to bottom, and from right to left.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was hoping that there'd be a "simple" CSS solution that didn't require me to know how many nor the relative positions of vertical text.  Having to use JS to calculate positions/sizes leads to some interesting coding for responsively sized text.

Alas I thought that changing writing mode to vertical did more than what appears to be just a transform rotate.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. Do you mean there may be several p elements, some with vertical and some with horizontal text? Maybe yo might create a more complex example code if so.

Comment: The text will actually be user-generated so the level of complexity could be high(er). As it is I found that adding display: grid; to the CSS for the DIV seems to address my first/simple example.

Comment: Can you give a more complex example so we can find a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but I'm posting comments but the comments disappear... The text will be user-generated so I don't know how much will be vertical. As it is I found that simply setting the DIV's css to display: grid; (without setting any other grid related CSS) does what I want in a simple example.

Comment: So is the problem solved or not?

Comment: At the very simplest level the problem as I presented is solved but when the complexity increases a little, it fails. For example, if I have some normal text followed by two pieces of vertical text I expect/hope the vertical text is displayed next to each other instead one is underneath the other. To me it looks like writing-mode is in its infancy.

Comment: So please edit the snippet you have given to show a more realistic example of the problem as currently it looks as though it is solved. In particular stress the need for two vertical texts to be next to each other as if they are in 'normal' elements this won't happen.

Comment: I've edited the original code to show a slightly more complex example. Ideally if there is vertical text following another vertical text in the HTML then they display next to each other (and not one under the other.)

Comment: I can’t see any edit to the code in the question. What has changed, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what's going on. I post comments that later disappear. I make edits that later get reverted. Some admin person is suggesting changes but there doesn't appear any way for me to accept their changes. Now I see that my edit is waiting to be approved.

Comment: Are you editing your actual question, not one of the answers?